# Why is Webelement hashcode is same after apply map in stream?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-8, java-stream

While learning Selenium automation with Stream API, I am facing an issue. Here are details

URL:https://vins-udemy.s3.amazonaws.com/java/html/java8-stream-table.html

Case:
Click on the checkbox of all Male.

Code to click on All 5 Checkbox of Male:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr"))
    .stream().skip(1)
    .filter(webElement -> webElement.getText().contains("Male"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")))
    .forEach(e -> e.click());
```

**Issue:
It is only clicking on the first check box of the table all 5 times.**

I tried to fetch hashcode of web element before applying the **map** in steam and here is code and result:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr"))
    .stream().skip(1)
    .filter(webElement -> webElement.getText().contains("Male"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .stream()
    .peek(e -> System.out.println(e.hashCode()))
    .map(e -> e.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")))
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.hashCode()));
```

Result:

```
204244715
1697377069
-162053676
1697377069
-1812804412
1697377069
-496584357
1697377069
-1688807037
1697377069
```

**Hashcode of web element is 1697377069 for all after applying map.**

I am not able to understand here that why the hash code of WebElement is the same after using Map for stream.

Comment: Off-topic, but `collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` is completely useless.

Comment: How is the hash code method of that class implemented? Why do you think a stream operation should change the state of an object in that stream?

Comment: @GhostCat I am thinking that Map is doing some strange thing here. Because if u notice series of hashcode then it is different for each webelement map but gets same after applying map . and due to that Selenium is only clicking on first web element of table

Comment: The more reasonable assumption is expressed by one of the other statements: most likely, your map maps different things to the SAME webelement. You aren't changing anything, but creating a sequence that contains the same object multiple times.

Comment: @GhostCat Exactly this is what happening !!! but why is that happening ? that's question

Comment: I would start by removing anything that isn't relevant. Why use streams and such a complicated expression? Focus on that part that causes the trouble. And if the map call gives the wrong result then you have to look at the input you give it.

Comment: Minor, but note that hashcodes are not required to change. It is totally valid for a hashcode to just always return the same number. Id suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: @Zabuzard As written before, that really depends on the how hashCode is implemented for that class. which was like the second the OP was told to look into.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's related to your `XPath` expression.

From w3schools it says:

> //book => Selects all book elements no matter where they are in the
> document

I think each of your elements is being mapped to the same element from the point of the root of your websites document. It's little bit odd, since one would assume `e.findElement(${theXPath})` will be evaluated relative to the current node `e`. Looks like it's not happening and the `XPath` is still being evaluated on the root element/ whole document of the page.

Try to adjust the way you're trying to locate the checkbox elements. E.g. adding a `.` to instruct the `XPath` to start from the current node like:

```
By.xpath(".//input[@type='checkbox']")
```

This should take your current node as the "root search contaxt" and serve you the elements you're looking for (different hashcodes).

In your case your `XPath` could probably also simplified to the following, to make it even easier and avoid the confusion overall:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[text()=\"Male\"]/input[@type='checkbox']")) ...
```

You can simply iterate over it and don't need to map it anymore.

More on `XPath` internals you can read e.g. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

---

**EDIT:**

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837735/relative-xpath-from-list-of-webelements), you might find it useful as well.

Comment: No, it is stream map issue. here is working code with stream without map with same xpath. driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr")).
                stream().skip(1).filter(webElement -> webElement.getText().contains("Male")).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().
                forEach(e->e.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='checkbox']")).click());

Comment: As I can see it's not the same XPath since you changed it from "//input..." to ".//input..." (note the second one starting with a "." before the slashes), so exactly what I've explained in my answer. So it's not a stream/ map issue, but an XPath issue. Also I'd suggest to replace the "collect().stream()" part with map() again since it's more readable and efficient. Feel free to try it once again and to let me know if it works. If the answer helped you I'd appreciate it a lot when you also officially accept my answer. BR Sebastian